# daily() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=\['remind'\])
def callback_verse(message):
r = requests.get("http://russian-poetry.ru/Random.php").text
soup = bs(r, "html.parser")
m = soup.find("title").text
b = soup.find("pre").text
msg = m + b
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(commands=\['daily'\])
def daily(update):
JobQueue.run_repeating(callback=callback_verse, interval=10, first=0, )
```

I get daily() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' error

I tried to use context, but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=\['daily'\])
def daily(update):
JobQueue.run_repeating(callback=callback_verse, interval=10, first=0, )
```

To:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=\['daily'\])
@staticmethod
def daily(update):
    JobQueue.run_repeating(callback=callback_verse, interval=10, first=0, )
```

Or:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=\['daily'\])
def daily(self, update):
    JobQueue.run_repeating(callback=callback_verse, interval=10, first=0, )
```

Comment: Did you mean to omit the `staticmethod` decoration from your third option?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for mistake.